# python : replace string in file by the content of an another file

Tags: python

I have 2 files src and dest

```
#cat src
lundi,mardi,mercredi,jeudi

# cat dest
janvier fevrier 
mars avril mai  
juillet aout  
septembre octobre
```

With python , I want to replace the string "mai" in the file dest by the content of the file src. The result wil be

```
# cat dest
janvier fevrier  
mars avril lundi,mardi,mercredi,jeudi  
juillet aout  
septembre octobre
```

Thanks you for help

I try those script but it is negative

1-

```
import os, sys  
    with open("src","r") as s:  
        with open("dst","w") as d:  
            for ligne in dst:  
                sligne=ligne.rstrip().split(" ")  
                for n in sline:  
                    sline=mai  
                    dst.str.replace("mai","src")
```

2-

```
d = open("dst","w")      
s = open("src","r")  
data=s.read()  
s.close()  
for n in dst:  
    data = data.replace("mai","s")   
    d.write(data)  
    d.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: You can read the documentation of python strings here http://docs.python.org/library/string.html

Answer (score 4):

1. Open src and dest for reading.
2. Read their contents into variables.
3. Close open files.  (maybe use context manager for this if you know what that is ... ).
4. Replace 'mai' in dest with the contents of src (using `string.replace`).
5. re-open dest for writing.
6. Write the new data.
7. *Smile.

*optional, though highly encouraged

Comment: I try those script but it is negative

1-  
import os, sys  
    with open("src","r") as s:  
        with open("dst","w") as d:  
            for ligne in dst:  
                sligne=ligne.rstrip().split(" ")  
                for n in sline:  
                sline=mai  
                dst.str.replace("mai","src") 

2-   
d = open("dst","w")      
s = open("src","r")  
data=s.read()  
s.close()  
for n in dst:  
    data = data.replace("mai","s")   
d.write(data)  
d.close()

Comment: @user1662958 -- As I said earlier, Add this code in your question.  Looking at it here in a comment, it is impossible to read (whitespace is important in python).  To edit your original question, just click on the little "edit" link beneath it and you can add the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("src",'r') as file:
    src = file.read()
    file.close()

with open("dest",'r') as file:
    dest = file.read()
    file.close()

dest.replace('mai',src)

with open("dest",'w') as file:
    file.write(dest)
    file.close()
```

Comment: * I try your script but the file dest is the same it is not changing ,   but on the screen the output result is good.    * The writing mode have no effect

Comment: No need to `file.close` if you use a context manager.  Also, `file` is a builtin type in python, while you can use it as a variable name, it's probably safer to use a different name.  Finally (and most importantly), this question is tagged as homework.  It's typically not advisable to just *give* answers to homework problems.  (guiding toward a solution is much more helpful).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you everybody,
   I resolve my problem. This is my proposition

```
with open("src","r") as file1:
     src = file1.read()
     src = src.rstrip()
     with open("dst","r") as file2:
         dst=file2.read()
         resultat=dst.replace('mai',src)
         with open("dst","w") as file2:
             file2.write(resultat)
```